# MongoDB application server IPTables

Tags: mongodb, firewall

I have 2 servers, one nginx/PHP and a mongoDB server. I have configured the mongoDB server's iptables correctly and I can connect to it with the nginx server when its firewall is down.  However, when I turn on the firewall. It stops working.  What should be open on the application server for it to connect to the MongoDB?

I am using the default ports on my mongo db server.  Here is an output of iptables on my web server.

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  { MongDB IP }        anywhere            tcp dpt:27017 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http state   NEW,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https state NEW,ESTABLISHED          

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             { MongDB IP }       tcp spt:27017 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:http state ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:https state ESTABLISHED
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a sharded cluster or have changed the [default ports used by MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/default-mongodb-port/), the only port you need to have open from your application server is 27017 on your MongoDB server.

The default ports used by MongoDB are:

- 27017 (standalone mongod)
- 27018 (mongod --shardsvr)
- 27019 (mongod --configsvr)
- 28017 (web status page .. you should not have this enabled in production)

The MongoDB documentation includes examples for [Configuring Linux `iptables` Firewall for MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-linux-iptables-firewall/).

You may also want to check the [`bind_ip`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#bind_ip) value (if set) to make sure your `mongod` is listening to the network interface that the application server is trying to connect to.  By default `mongod` listens to all interfaces, but some distributions may limit this to localhost on initial install.

Comment: See above for my Iptables